# Drinking water before nightfall , on pesach evening

Tags: halacha, passover, kiddush

Would one be allowed to drink water between shkiah - dusk, and tzais - nightfall, on the first night of Pesach, being that you can’t make Kiddush then anyways, and if yes, what if it fell out on Shabbos?

Can we compare  it to the morning before praying, when he is allowed to drink water, even though it’s  really the time of obligation, only the person himself can’t make Kiddush until  he prays?

Comment: You can make kiddush then! You just can't fulfill your obligation in four cups (according to the minority opinion in rishonim whose opinion is generally followed)

Comment: Wouldn’t that be a ברכה לבטלה?

Comment: Chas veshalom, no. It just messes with the standard order of the seder (since later you'll have to drink a first cup with no kiddush on it) so we don't do it unless you're a soldier or doctor or something where you won't have wine/matza available later at night. Then might as well fulfill your kiddush obligation when you can, and let pikuach nefesh etc. override the seder later on.

Comment: True, but just because you’re allowed to make קידוש then - only בשעת הדחק - doesn’t prove that you   can’t eat

Comment: What else would prove that you can't eat?? The time and nature of the obligation of kiddush is the same as every shabbat/chag and the prohibition on eating before it should be the same as well since *nothing about kiddush is different* (and there's some secondary external obligation of four cups that we'd rather wait to fulfill both in one go but has nothing to do with eating before)

Comment: How would that be different than drinking water before שחרית - the prohibition of making קידוש then is also  “external, secondary”

Comment: Don't know what prohibition you're talking about, there is no obligation of kiddush before Shacharit (according to the Rosh the way "we" paskin). You couldn't do kiddush even if you tried.

Comment: But there would have been  a חיוב if not for the “external” problem

Comment: Let's say you say on Friday night "konam wine and bread to me until 11 PM".  Would that mean you can eat whatever else you want until then?

Comment: "But there would have been a חיוב if not for the 'external' problem” No that's still not true. The time for kiddush in the morning is after davening (accd to the Rosh). The time for kiddush at night is night.

Comment: I guess you’re right

Comment: @Heshy You would still need to make kiddush before you eat. The kiddush can be made on what you are going to eat (Reb Avraham B Rambam in Teshuva פד)

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy ok fine, let's say you make a neder on everything besides water

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy also he doesn't say that, he says if you don't have wine or bread you should say kiddush without Hashem's name as a zeicher.  It's not the real thing.

Comment: I still think we might be able to compare it to the morning before שחרית, because  מצד the time,  the חיוב itself is still there - the only reason why he’s פטור is because he personally didn’t daven yet - but someone who already davend is obligated to make קידוש at that very moment

Comment: " the time, the חיוב itself is still there" this is still false the way we paskin. The Raavyah holds that and he holds you can't drink water before davening on shabbat. The Rosh holds the chiyuv is not there and therefore you can drink water before davening.

Comment: But “before davening” is not a time - it depends on the person, who is forbidden to eat before davening  - had he already davend, or if he would be פטור or unable to daven - he would  have already been able to  make Kiddush  at that moment - so the problem is not the time, but a side reason relating to the person - yet, like you said, we pasken that he can still drink, so why would this case be any different - here too, even though, like you said, it is time to make Kiddush - there still is a side problem - The חיוב of ד׳ כוסות

Comment: The Rosh says the chiyuv isn't there yet and that's why he can drink, not that the chiyuv is there and there's a side issue. You don't like the Rosh but that doesn't change what he said. There's no point in saying this over and over again.

Comment: The Bach says on siman 472 that one can bring in Pesach early, as such one can make kiddush and drink before hand

Answer (score 1):

Bein Hashmshos is a period of uncertainty between day and night. Shekiya is the beginning of this period when the sun sets. From this time on there is an uncertainty whether one can make kiddush yet, we therefore, wait untll  after three stars are visible before making Kiddush.

According to [the SA](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.3?lang=he&with=Translations&lang2=he), both men and women have the same obligation to make kiddush on Shabbos and [Pesach](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.472.14?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), because they are both commanded to observe these holy days. Therefore, just as one cannot drink anything before kiddush on Shabbos, the same applies on Pesach.

As double AA pointed out, can one bring in pesach early like people do for Shabbos? Can one make kiddush after plag before Tzeitz? The [SA](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.472.1?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) says when it is dark then one should start. The [Mishna Berura](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.472.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and [Eshel Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org/Eshel_Avraham_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.472.3?lang=he&with=Halakhah%20ConnectionsList&lang2=he) both point out that one can only start the Seder and kiddush when it is night. Therefore one can only start when it is night and can't eat or drink before kiddush.

**edit**
Reb Meneshe Klein [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1879&pgnum=62) seems to be more leninat and rule if there is a need one can drink.

### In short

I think one would not be allowed to drink before Kiddush. (Obviously, a Rabbi must be consulted) unless under certain circumstances.

Comment: The important part of this answer is "From this time on the Mitzvah of kiddush begins. One should only make kiddush though once it is dark." which is not only unsourced but (on its face) contradictory.

Comment: Ok well it's still unsourced and I'm not convinced its true. Maybe we vadai can't say kiddush during safek night, and maybe a doubtful kiddush obligation is insufficient to generate a prohibition on eating

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for pointing out to me where my answers were lacking. I don't know if i answered your points I will try and do more research